# Could not find implementation class for plugin error when using plugin “java-gradle-plugin”

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Gradle 4.10.2

NOTE: I posted the same question in the Gradle Forum page but have had 0 traction after 1 week.

I’ve read [Could not find implementation class for plugin error when using Gradle 4.1+](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-find-implementation-class-for-plugin-error-when-using-gradle-4-1/24279) but I may have a different issue, but I’m not sure.

This is my first time writing a plugin so I’m just following [Writing Gradle Plugins](https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-plugins/) tutorial, and [Gradle Plugin Development Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html).

Here’s my plugin’s `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-gradle-plugin'

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        simplePlugin {
            id = 'org.example.greeting.greeting-plugin'
            implementationClass = 'org.example.greeting.GreetingPlugin'
        }
    }
}
```

However when I get this when I build

```
$ ./gradlew clean build

**> Task :jar**

:jar: A valid plugin descriptor was found for org.example.greeting-plugin.properties but the implementation class org.example.greeting.GreetingPlugin was not found in the jar.

**BUILD SUCCESSFUL** in 0s
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The article has one creating a `/top-level/buildSrc/src/...` directory. I moved the `src/` tree to just `/top-level/src/...` and it worked.